# I want to replace the first six digits of an account number to be ###### and the last three to be ### using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
let regex = /(^\d{6})|(\d{3}$)/gm;
n = n.toString();
n = n.replace(regex,'#');
return '#####' + n + "##"
```

This is my regex but it returns `#5225#` not the expected result which is `######5225###`.

Comment: How are you _applying_ that regex? Presumably `.replace(regex, '#')`, in which case replacing the whole match with a single hash symbol is _what you asked for_. Maybe look into passing a _function_ as the replacer.

Comment: Firstly: why do this with a regex? Secondly: a regex does not replace anything, the problem is how you are using the regex and probably just replacing each match with a single #

Comment: Do you need to "pre-validate" the input string as a string of digits? If not, there is no need of a regex in these scenarios. Also, what should happen to `123456123`? Or just `123`?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: function account(n){
   let regex = /(^(\d{6})|(\d{3})$)/gm;
   n = n.toString();
   n = n.replace(regex,'#');
   return '#####' + n + "##"

}
console.log(account(7301205225084)) this is my code

Comment: Why are you trying to `replace` if you actually want to extract the unmasked part and pad with `#`? Seems to complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: So what is the correct way to do it

Comment: @Simbarashe my regex skills are low, so here's plain JavaScript: `function account(n) {
    const arr = n.split('');
    const firstPart = arr.slice(0,6);
    const secondPart = arr.slice(6,10);
    const thirdPart = arr.slice(10);
    const finalResult = firstPart.map(num => '#').concat(secondPart).concat(thirdPart.map(num => '#'));
    return finalResult.join('');
}
account('1234567891234');`
You can make this one-liner but I just made it more verbose for easier understanding.

Comment: I re-read the post trying to understand what's wrong with the downvotes, when the question is clear enough; provides unexpected & expected results. So to fit your code structure my code above could be shortened to: `function account(n) {
    const arr = n.split('');
    const secondPart = arr.slice(6,10).join('');
    return \`######${secondPart}###\`;
}
account('1234567891234');`

Comment: @Aleksandar DV and CV had been cast at a time when OP didn't provide anything but the regex leaving it unclear how it was being applied.

Answer (score 0):

just you string slice, remove the first 6 and last 3 and return the result with additional `#` before and after

```js
function replaceChar( char ) {
    return '######' + char.toString().slice(6,-3) + '###'
}
console.log(replaceChar(9999991111333))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a replacer function and use repeat with the length of the match.

```js
const regex = /(^\d{6})|(\d{3}$)/gm;
let n = 111111234555;
n = n.toString();
n = n.replace(regex, x => '#'.repeat(x.length));
console.log(n);
```

or using substring

```js
let n = 111111234555;
const result = '######' + n.toString().substring(6,9) + '###';
console.log(result);
```